# Is Android Gatt Disconnect Clean?

Tags: android-bluetooth, android-ble

I am testing my BLE Android App on different Phones ranging from Android 5.0 to 7.1. I am seeing that even though the Disconnection event occur the next BLE connection takes time with intermittent inability to reconnect.
Is the Android disconnection actually taking place while invoking the disconnection.How to make it disconnect clean? 
As a workaround I am waiting for some time after disconnection to reconnect again.
My app requires to frequently connect after disconnect but due to previous un-clean disconnect my subsequent connect doesnt works properly.
I even try .close after .disconnect but no difference.

Comment: What do you mean by `clean disconnect`? Do you use `RxAndroidBle` library as your tag suggest?

Comment: No I don't use this library , I am using Android APIs only.I removed the RxAndroidBle Tag.

Comment: Is the time in which you are not able to connect about 20 seconds long?

Answer (score 0):

> Is the Android disconnection actually taking place while invoking the disconnection?

Calling `BluetoothGatt.disconnect()` only starts the process of disconnection. To be sure when it will actually happen you need to track `BluetoothGattCallback.onConnectionStateChanged()`.

Comment: Disconnect does not clean connection even after 20 seconds of successfully terminating the connection. Anyone found a way to clean the connection completely?

Comment: You're looking for `BluetoothGatt.close()` probably.